# How to fix the code this QR Code Scanner?

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I almost made an app that scan QR code with WebView in Android Studio, but it's not done yet. After my app scan the code, The app is just turned off without result. Can you guys find the problem from my code?

This is whole code of app.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.qr_code_scanner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    WebView webView;
    Button scanBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scanBtn = findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onClick(View v) {
        scanCode();
    }

    private void scanCode() {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivity.class);
        //        integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
        //        integrator.setRequestCode(200)
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scanning Code");
        integrator.initiateScan();
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() != null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(result.getContents());
                builder.setTitle("Scanning Result");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Scan Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        scanCode();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Finish", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Results", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(result.getContents());
        }
    }
}
```

CaptureActivity.java

```
package com.example.qr_code_scanner;

public class CaptureActivity extends com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity {
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.qr_code_scanner">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.QR_Code_Scanner">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.qr_code_scanner"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scanBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="scan"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you're getting errors, post the logcat. It's very time-consuming to find out what the error is just by looking at your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not define your Webview id you are directly calling

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
```

You are missing this line

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

One more thing you are using zxing you need to add some line in the manifest follow this [Zxing Documentation](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)